# Can't push simple golang project to heroku

Tags: go, heroku

My project "testheeroku7777" consist of two files.
main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

fmt.Println("Hello world!")

}
```

Procfile:

```
web: testheeroku7777
```

When I push:

```
testheeroku7777> git push heroku master
```

It gives an error:

```
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 645.21 KiB | 5.92 MiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/go.tgz
remote:        More info:     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to testheeroku7777.
remote: To https://git.heroku.com/testheeroku7777.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/testheeroku7777.git'
```

I've read provided links but I have no idea about this error.

Comment: If i build it and run the app locally, it works. `go build` `heroku local web` gives `[WARN] No ENV file found
16:18:32 web.1   |  Hello world!
16:18:32 web.1   Exited Successfully`

Comment: If you want to generate dependencies for an existing project: ```go mod tidy```

Answer (score 2):

This issue has to do with Go’s new dependency management system. Heroku is looking for a dependency management system in your project, and can’t find one. That’s why it’s throwing an error. Even though yours is a simple project, Heroku must have a dependency-management system that it can recognise.

Using Go modules is the [officially-sanctioned method](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) of dependency-management. But – and it’s a big but – a surprising quirk of Go modules is that Go modules don’t work for projects that are within the `GOPATH`.

When Go started, the developers made a big thing of having all projects in one place, the `GOPATH`. All the documentation was explicit on this – this is where your go code has to stored, it won’t run from anywhere else. But now, if you’re writing code that needs Go modules – and any code that’s going on heroku needs Go modules – the directories for that code must be outside `GOPATH`. I don’t know why they don’t make that more explicit, but that seems to be the way it is.

So, to get your code working, what you need to do is:

1. Move your project to somewhere outside `GOPATH` – the desktop, say,
   in the name of originality.
2. Create a remote git repository with the same name as your current
   project.
3. Then create a go module file by typing, at the terminal command
   prompt in your local directory, `go mod init
   github.com/myGithubUserName/myProjectName`
4. Next, create a local git repository by typing `git init` in the terminal.
5. Identify the remote repository you created earlier by typing `git
   remote add origin
   http//www.github.com/myGithubUserName/myProjectName.git` in the
   terminal.
6. Write some excellent code.
7. Type `git add . && git commit -m “first commit”` at the prompt to
   commit your code.
8. Type `git push -u origin master` to update the remote repository.

After all that, and only after all that, are you ready to type `git push heroku master`. The only consolation is that all should run smoothly now.

There are earlier dependency-management systems as mentioned by other posters, like `govendor` and `dep`, but Go modules are the officially-sanctioned method and I guess we’re all as well to adapt to it now as later. The most popular tutorial about Go modules seems to be this one: https://roberto.selbach.ca/intro-to-go-modules/. A search will find a few others too.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't have the Go runtime installed in the base image, and therefore requires that you utilize the [go buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go) to build your app. However, this also requires that you use a vendoring tool such as dep, or govendor, which means this very basic app, by itself, unfortunately won't work.

Comment: I tried to specify that build pack `heroku create testheeroku7777 -b https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go.git` but push gives the same error. Why do I need to use a vendoring tool and how can I do it?

Comment: There are a bunch if different supported tools I use govendor, which is [supported](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-dependencies-via-govendor). I’m actually not sure why there is a hard vendoring requirement, but my guess would be that it solves the GOPATH problem in a reasonable way, without forcing you to create a src/ lib/ /bin directory structure (mimicking what GOPATH would expect).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you ever get it resolved?